# How can I find out if a Tcl_Obj is a certain kind of ttk:: entity, such as ttk:entry?

Tags: c++, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am working with a legacy (Desktop-style, as they're now known) Windows application built mostly in C and C++. When this application is running on a touchscreen Windows laptop, I need to automatically show the touch keyboard when the user taps inside an entry box on a dialog screen. This behavior is very common, and as far as I can tell, Microsoft *disabled* this formerly automatic behavior in Windows 8/8.1, and will be re-enabling it in Windows 10.

So... I can programmatically show the touch keyboard, that part is solved. What I'm trying to do now is catch when a ttk::entry widget receives focus and then activate the keyboard. The closest I've come is inside tk8.5.9/generic/tkFocus.c. There is a method called Tk_FocusObjCmd:

```
 /*
 *--------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Tk_FocusObjCmd --
 *
 *  This function is invoked to process the "focus" Tcl command. See the
 *  user documentation for details on what it does.
 *
 * Results:
 *  A standard Tcl result.
 *
 * Side effects:
 *  See the user documentation.
 *
 *--------------------------------------------------------------
 */

int
Tk_FocusObjCmd(
    ClientData clientData,  /* Main window associated with interpreter. */
    Tcl_Interp *interp,     /* Current interpreter. */
    int objc,           /* Number of arguments. */
    Tcl_Obj *CONST objv[])  /* Argument objects. */
{
```

This method is given, among other things, an array of Tcl_Obj objects. What I'm trying to do is find out if the one being acted on is of a certain type, such as ttk::entry. If it is, I will launch the touch keyboard. I've tried using object->typePtr->name, but that doesn't give me what I'd expected, and sometimes it crashes (haven't figured out why yet):

```
char *objectType = objv[1]->typePtr->name;

if (objectType)
{
    printf("Object Type: %s\n", objectType); // don't do this, it breaks sometimes.
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. I would greatly appreciate any insight to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this very thoroughly wrong. What you *should* do is instead *assume* that you're passed a widget name (something like `.a2.b5.c9`) and then ask Tk to tell you what the class of the widget with that name is.

```
winfo class .a2.b5.c9
```

For an instance of a `ttk::entry`, this will return `TEntry` (unless you changed it by passing in the `-class` option on widget creation).

From the C level, you'd query the class by using `Tk_Class()`, which takes a single `Tk_Window` argument (which you can obtain via `Tk_NameToWindow`, passing in the string form of the argument value, which in turn you can obtain from `Tcl_GetString`). But it might be simpler to just use `Tcl_VarEval`, assuming non-evil window names…

```c
if (Tcl_VarEval(interp, "winfo class ", Tcl_GetString(objPtr), NULL) == TCL_OK) {
    const char *className = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));
    // ...
}
```

(The truly cautious or those really keen on speed will use `Tcl_EvalObjv`, but that's a bit more complex.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used your example technique and it worked. When I click in a ttk::entry field, it shows the class name as TEntry.